# Wireshark capture suspicious outbound traffic

Tags: wireshark

Norton is telling me. We have detected a large amount of suspicious outbound traffic on your system. What Wireshark filters can I use to find this traffic. How can I tell what port this suspicious outbound traffic is using?

Answer (score 1):

With Wireshark, you can get an idea of the type of traffic leaving your system by first filtering on its IP address, e.g., "`ip.src eq 192.168.1.100`" ... where `192.168.1.100` represents your system's IP address and then viewing:

- Statistics -> Protocol Hierarchy, which will give you a high-level breakdown on the type of traffic present as well as various statistics like bytes, packets, etc.
- Statistics -> Conversations -> IPv4, which will tell you the amount of packets, bytes etc per IPv4 "conversation" (you may need to check the box that indicates *"Limit to display filter"* in order to isolate only the outbound packets from your system)  You can right-click on a conversation and "apply as filter -> selected -> ..." to isolate a particular IP conversation for further analysis, and you can also look at the IPv6, TCP or UDP conversations as well by selecting those tabs instead of the IPv4 tab.  The data is also sortable by whichever column you're interested in, simply click on the column heading to sort by that column.  The TCP or UDP tab will indicate the respective port(s) that the traffic is communicating over.
- Statistics -> Endpoints -> ... is similar to Statistics -> Conversations, but lists each endpoint separately.  If you *"Limit to display filter"*, then you will see each endpoint your system is communicated with listed on a separate row.
- Analyze -> Expert Information may also provide you with some additional information about the traffic you've captured, and you can *"Limit to Display Filter"* there as well.

Well, this should hopefully get you started.